# Spring Data Neo4j: Easiest way to save Node with references to its related nodes

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'am wondering whats the easiest and best way to save new nodes with references to its related nodes.

I've already seen the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73489008/spring-data-neo4j-reference-related-nodes-without-overwriting-them-on-save) where the use of projections is recommended.

I was wondering if this is the only and/or best way to save nodes.I've tried it out and for me the code looks somewhat redundant. As an example I have User-Nodes and Post-Nodes:

```java
public class User {
  
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  String id;
  String name;
  String email;

  @Relationship(type = "FOLLOWER" direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMMING)
  Set<User> follower;

}
```

```java
public class Post {
  
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  String id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String imageUrl;

  @Relationship(type = "POSTED_BY" direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
  User user;
}
```

In my example a new Post will be sent over a REST-API which will look like:

```json
{
"title":"Title", 
"description": "Post description",
"imageUrl": "http//localhost:8080/assets/image.png",
"user": "[user id]"
}
```

So when saving the new Post I would like to save all properties and create a relation to the existing user node. However to do so I am currently having a Post-Projection Interface which has getters for all properties plus a getter for the User relation which returns a projection with just the id.

```java
public interface PostProjection extends IdProjection {
  String getTitle();
  String getDescription();
  String getImageUrl();
  IdProjection getUser();
}

public interface IdProjection {
  String getId();
}
```

The Post node can then be saved with `neo4jTemplate.saveAs(post,PostProjection.class)`.

So now to my main question if there is any other way to save a new post. With the current solution I need to create a projection interface with IdProjections for relationships for every node class I have in application. This seems to be a bit redundant as from my point of view this seems to be a general use case.

The other possible solution I tried out was to retrieve the user object from the database (also to check if the user exists). But in this case all the user's followers also get loaded which seems to be a bit overhead, especially when there are many relationships.

So is there a way to save node with references to related notes without creating seperate projection classes for each node classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in a project of mine, and I don't believe Spring Data Neo4j is overwriting the end node any more. I believe this was changed to do a lookup before saving (MERGE).

However, if it is still overwriting the values, I would be inclined to create a custom query that does a MATCH on the related nodes (User, in your case) and then does a MERGE on the new relationship. That would ensure it does not overwrite existing values. Hope this helps!